# TypeError: Parser.parse() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'

Tags: python, parsing, lex, ply

Next, I'm still trying to learn basic programming and I came across an error and I'm not able to solve it.
The code consists of a parser using the ply library
Code:

```
import sys
import ply.lex as lex
import ply.yacc as yacc

class Parser:
    def __init__(self, lexer):
        self.lexer = lexer
        self.parser = yacc.yacc(module=self)

    def parse(self, data):
        self.lexer.input(data)
        return self.parser.parse()
    # lexer rules
    tokens = (
        "PROGRAMA",
        "ID",
        "INT",
        "FLOAT",
        "ASSIGNMENT",
        "IF",
        "ELSE",
        "PRINT",
        "LPAREN",
        "RPAREN",
        "SEMICOLON",
        "GREATER_THAN",
        "LESS_THAN",
        "EQUAL_TO",
        "STRING",
    )
    t_PROGRAMA = r"programa"
    t_ID = r"[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*"
    t_INT = r"[0-9]+"
    t_FLOAT = r"[0-9]+\.[0-9]+"
    t_ASSIGNMENT = r"="
    t_IF = r"if"
    t_ELSE = r"else"
    t_PRINT = r"print"
    t_LPAREN = r"()"
    t_RPAREN = r")"
    t_SEMICOLON = r";"
    t_GREATER_THAN = r">"
    t_LESS_THAN = r"<"
    t_EQUAL_TO = r"="
    t_STRING = r'"([^"\\]|\\["\\])*"'
    t_ignore = r" \t\r\n"
    def t_error(t):
        print("Illegal character '%s'" % t.value)
        t.lexer.skip(1)
    # parser rules
    precedence = (
        ("left", "GREATER_THAN", "LESS_THAN", "EQUAL_TO"),
        ("left", "+", "-"),
        ("left", "*", "/"),
        ("right", "UMINUS"),
    )
    def p_programa(p):
        """programa : PROGRAMA ID '{' var_decl+ stmt+ '}'"""
        print("programa:", p[2], p[4])
    def p_var_decl(p):
        """var_decl : 'var' ID ':' tipo ';'"""
        print("var_decl:", p[2], p[4], p[3])
    def p_tipo(p):
        """tipo : 'int' | 'float'"""
        print("tipo:", p[1])
    def p_stmt(p):
        """stmt : assignment | if_stmt | while_stmt | print_stmt"""
        print("stmt:", p[1])
    def p_assignment(p):
        """assignment : ID '=' expr ';'"""
        print("assignment:", p[1], p[3])
    def p_if_stmt(p):
        """if_stmt : 'if' '(' expr ')' '{' stmt+ '}' else_stmt"""
        print("if_stmt:", p[3], p[6], p[7])
    def p_else_stmt(p):
        """else_stmt : 'else' '{' stmt+ '}' ;"""
        print("else_stmt:", p[2])
    def p_while_stmt(p):
        """while_stmt : 'while' '(' expr ')' '{' stmt+ '}'"""
        print("while_stmt:", p[3], p[6])
    def p_print_stmt(p):
        """print_stmt : 'print' '(' expr ')' ';'"""
        print("print_stmt:", p[3])
    def p_expr(p):
        """expr : term expr_tail"""
        print("expr:", p[1], p[2])
    def p_expr_tail(p):
        """expr_tail : add_op term expr_tail | ;"""
        print("expr_tail:", p[1], p[2])
    def p_term(p):
        """term : factor term_tail"""
        print("term:", p[1], p[2])
    def p_term_tail(p):
        """term_tail : add_op factor term_tail | """
        print("term_tail:", p[1], p[2])
    def p_factor(p):
        """factor : ID | number | '(' expr ')'"""
        print("factor:", p[1])
    def p_add_op(p):
        """add_op : '+' | '-'"""
        print("add_op:", p[1])
    def p_mul_op(p):
        """mul_op : '*' | '/'"""
        print("mul_op:", p[1])
    def p_number(p):
        """number : SIGNED_INT | FLOAT"""
        print("number:", p[1])
    def p_signed_int(p):
        """signed_int : '+' SIGNED_INT | '-' SIGNED_INT | SIGNED_INT"""
        print("signed_int:", p[1])
    def p_float(p):
        """float : SIGNED_INT '.' SIGNED_INT | SIGNED_INT '.' | '.' SIGNED_INT"""
        print("float:", p[1])
    def p_error(t):
        print("Illegal character '%s'" % t.value)
        t.lexer.skip(1)
    
data = '''
        program Teste
        {
            var a = 10;
            var b = 20;
            float c = 3.14; 
            if (a > b){
                print("a > b");
            }
            else if (a < b){
                print("a < b");
            }
            else {
                print("a == b");
            }
            print("The sum of a and b is", add(a, b))}
    '''

sys.stdout.write(Parser.parse(data))
```

The expected output is a parse tree of the code, something like that.

```
program
    PROGRAMA
        Teste
    var_decl
        var
            a
            10
    var_decl
        var
            b
            20
    var_decl
        var
            c
            3.14
    if_stmt
        if
            (
                a
                >
                b
            )
            print
                "a > b"
        else_if
            (
                a
                <
                b
            )
            print
                "a < b"
        else
            print
                "a == b"
    print
        "The sum of a and b is"
        add
            a
            b
```

Comment: You need to create an instance of the class: `Parser(lexer).parse(data)`

Comment: Barmar, like that?
lexer = lex.lex()
parser = Parser(lexer)
result = parser.parse(data)

Some more errors appeared: 
WARNING: t_ignore contains a literal backslash '\'
ERROR: Regular expression for rule 't_LPAREN' matches empty string
ERROR: Invalid regular expression for rule 't_RPAREN'. unbalanced parenthesis at position 14
line 5, in <module>class Parser:
line 59, in Parserlexer = lex.lex()
line 909, in lexraise SyntaxError("Can't build lexer")

I will try to debug it, minimize these errors

Comment: That's the general structure. The specifics of your lexical rules and grammar you'll have to debug yourself.